# how to add header info to a wav file to get a same result as ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav

I'm trying to generate a .wav file with Fastspeech. When I save the data as .pcm file, and transfer it to .wav by ffmpeg, it works well.But when I just add a wav header info and save it into .wav, it sounds very noisy, What's wrong with my code?

code for pcm:

```
    wav = wav.astype(np.float32)
    wav = wav.tostring()
    with open('test.pcm', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(wav)
```

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -ar 16000 -i test.pcm file.wav  # works well
```

write wav straightly:

```
import struct

def pcm2wav(sample_rate, pcm_voice):
    if pcm_voice.startswith("RIFF".encode()):
        return pcm_voice
    else:
        sampleNum = len(pcm_voice)
        rHeaderInfo = "RIFF".encode()
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('i', sampleNum + 44)
        rHeaderInfo += 'WAVEfmt '.encode()
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('i', 16)
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('h', 1)
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('h', 1)
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('i', sample_rate)
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('i', sample_rate * int(32 / 8))
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack("h", int(32 / 8))
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack("h", 32)
        rHeaderInfo += "data".encode()
        rHeaderInfo += struct.pack('i', sampleNum)
        rHeaderInfo += pcm_voice
        return rHeaderInfo

# .......
# get data with FastSpeech model
wav = wav.astype(np.float32)
wav = wav.tostring()
wav = pcm2wav(16000, wav)
with open('test.wav', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(wav)   # many noisy sounds
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question and solved finally. I replaced  the first `struct.pack('h', 1)` to `struct.pack('h', 3)` and it works.

I found `scipy.io.wavfile.write` can generate a good wav file. Then I got the answer in the source code of this function.

```
if dkind == 'f':
    format_tag = WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT  # WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT=3
else:
    format_tag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM  # WAVE_FORMAT_PCM=1
# ...
fmt_chunk_data = struct.pack('<HHIIHH', format_tag, channels, fs,
                                 bytes_per_second, block_align, bit_depth)
```

My data is float32 type, so its format_tag should be 3, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good solution for this that doesn't involve 'hacking' in your own header.

You can subclass pydub.AudioSegment and overwrite the export() method to save to a io.BytesIO stream rather than to an actual file.

```py
# Original slice of AudioSegment.export()

if format == "raw" and (codec is not None or parameters is not None):
      raise AttributeError(
              'Can not invoke ffmpeg when export format is "raw"; '
              'specify an ffmpeg raw format like format="s16le" instead '
              'or call export(format="raw") with no codec or parameters')

  out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
  
# Updated code

  if format == "raw" and (codec is not None or parameters is not None):
      raise AttributeError(
              'Can not invoke ffmpeg when export format is "raw"; '
              'specify an ffmpeg raw format like format="s16le" instead '
              'or call export(format="raw") with no codec or parameters')

  out_f = io.BytesIO()
```

This will allow you to use AudioSegment as normal without saving to a file.